# PowerMockito whenNew thenReturn is not working for transitive classes

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have following scenario

```
Class A {
  someMethod() {
    B b = new B();
    b.someMethod();
  }
}

Class B {
  String someMethod() {
    C c = new C();
    return c.someMethod();
  }
}

Class C {
  String someMethod() {
    D d = new D();
    return d.getId()
  }
}

Class D {
  getId() {
    return "id123";
  }
}
```

what I am doing in my UT

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class, C.class})
MyTest {
  public void basicTest() {
    D mockDClass = mock(D.class);
    when(mockDClass.getId()).thenReturn("mockedId");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(D.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockClass);
  }
}
```

In my test, it should return `mockedId` but control goes to the actual method.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Does `whenNew` works when I do new in the class I test? And not for the case I described.

----------------------UPDATE---------------------
Wrote a simple module to test the above

```
public class A {
  public String someMethod() {
    B b = new B();
    return b.someMethod();
  }
}

public class B {
  public String someMethod() {
    C c = new C();
    return c.someMethod();
  }
}

public class C {
  public String someMethod() {
    D d = new D();
    return d.getId();
  }
}

public class D {
  public String getId() {
    return "id123";
  }
}
```

Test:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class, C.class})
public class ATest extends TestCase {
  @Test
  public void mockTest() {
    D mockD = mock(D.class);
    when(mockD.getId()).thenReturn("this is from mock");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(D.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockD);
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.someMethod());
  }
}
```

And the output of this test looks like this:
[image]

This small test works so I am doing something wrong in the actual test.

Answer (score 1):

whenNew should works every time the object you mocks get instantiated. You should actually replace the line 'when(D.getId()).thenReturn("mockedId")' with 'when(mockDClass.getId).thenReturn("mockedId")'.
The following code snippets should works:

C test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({C.class})
public class CTest {

  @Test
  public void someMethodTest() throws Exception {
    D mockDClass = mock(D.class);
    when(mockDClass.getId()).thenReturn("mockedId");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(D.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockDClass);
    C c = new C();

    String response = c.someMethod();
    verifyNew(D.class).withNoArguments();
    assertEquals("mockedId", response);
  }
}
```

D test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DTest {

  @Test
  public void testId() throws Exception {
    D mockDClass = mock(D.class);
    when(mockDClass.getId()).thenReturn("mockedId");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(D.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockDClass);
    D d = new D();

    verifyNew(D.class).withNoArguments();
    String response = d.getId();
    assertEquals("mockedId", response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I actually have `mockDClass.getid()` and it did not work, updated the question as well.

Comment: Can you share the actual test method you are running?

Comment: added the full module

Comment: sorry forgot whenNew

Comment: test which update works so I might be doing something wrong in the actual code, ty for the help though

Comment: u r welcome. May be in your actual code you forgot to let powermock prepare all the classes it needs?. If you remove C.class from the prepareForTest annotation, your small test case should return the string from real method call (id123)